# Safari Extension Popover Links

Tags: javascript, safari, safari-extension, popover

Is it possible to have a link work in a Safari popover? I've done just about everything I can think of, but it appears that the adding links to popovers only changes the appearance, and doesn't result in anything clickable, either with href or onclick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add onclick listener on href or div

```
.onclick = safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.openTab().url = "http://www.yourdomain.com/";
```

Comment: Do you have a more full code example? I tried what you said with `$('#target0').onclick = function(){safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.openTab().url = "http://www.yourdomain.com/"};` and it didn't work either. I initially did `$('#target0').onclick = safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.openTab().url = "http://www.yourdomain.com/";`, but it just opened a new tab to yourdomain.com immediately.

Comment: You can't use .onclick with jQuery objects. Try `$('#target0').click(function(){...})` or `$('#target0').on('click', function(){...})` instead.

Comment: var successDiv = document.getElementById('statusBlogSpan'); successDiv.onclick = safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.openTab().url = "http://www.yourdomain.com/"; Try it.

Comment: @canisbos The `.on('click', ...)` worked, the other didn't. Thanks a lot, I was about to give up on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
var link = document.querySelector('#~~~');
link.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.openTab().url = "http://~~"
})
```